# How to change default language in qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

How to change the default language in qt designer anyone has solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals that this is not yet possible: see [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/88219/changing-the-default-language-of-qt-designer) and [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/88496/how-can-i-change-qt-designer-s-language/2). QtDesigner follows your system language, so changing that might help.

Answer (score 3):

you can make designer fail to find translation file (C:\5.15.2\mingw81_32\translations\designer_zh_CN.qm in my case) so it will fallback to english.

Answer (score 0):

until now there is no professional solution so i will suggest to try my solution:
go to Qt Designer directory ex: (C:\xxx\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt) and go to \translations directory and rename/remove all language you don't need so your program will take the rest language as default language
ex rename files :
qtscript_fr renamed to -qtscript_fr-
assistant_fr renamed to -assistant_fr-...
this worked for me

Comment: Isn’t it the same solution as the one given in @chatgirl's answer?

Comment: i guess yes but she/he doesn't provide details on how to do that !